# How to run a javascript function on all the rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When a cell is clicked the function is suppose to run.
Right now it is working only on the first row.

When i click on the button on a row i want that specific row to affect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function loadHistory() {
    $('#btn').data('valType', 'more');
    $('#btn').click(function() {
      var id = $('#btn').data("valType")
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use class selector, instead of id.

For example, yo have any list:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        Chair
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        Sofa
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        Table
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is kind of working but not how i wanted. when i click a button on a row i want that specific row to be affected not all the rows. right now with ur codes it is affecting all the rows

Comment: Not sure! In my code, only one row is being deleted, not all of them

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML code it is a bit more difficult to answer you, but I try.
Usually the ID is unique, so it's assigned to only one element, so try using the class selector.

Then another thing, I don't know if this is your case, if you go to create the other lines dynamically, the jQuery `.click ()` function will not be able to manage the clicks on the elements created after loading the page. In this case use `$.on('click', '.yourClass', function)`.

I hope I was helpful!